# General error:3734 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id' for constraint 'posts_user_id_foreign' in the referenced table'users'

Tags: laravel

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3734 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id' for constraint 'posts_user_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'users' (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

  at D:\multimedia-projects-main (1)\multimedia-projects-main\jobsearch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:761
    757▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    758▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    759▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    760▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 761▕             throw new QueryException(
    762▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    763▕             );
    764▕         }
    765▕     }

  1   D:\multimedia-projects-main (1)\multimedia-projects-main\jobsearch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:546
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3734 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id' for constraint 'posts_user_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'users'")

  2   D:\multimedia-projects-main (1)\multimedia-projects-main\jobsearch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:546
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

my code look like this for the foreign
public function up()

```
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('post_id')->unique()->nullable(false);
            $table->biginteger('user_id')->unasigned()->index();         
            $table->biginteger('company_id')->unasigned()->index();          
            $table->biginteger('job_id')->unasigned()->index();          
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
             $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs');
        });
    }
```

this is for the user

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->foreignid('companyid');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

the rest is similar

already try to change the foreign key into big integer and to integer already try to change the name of the foreign reference but still not working

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a parameter in `$schema->id()` function, the column will be named with given parameter.

In your code you have renamed `id` columns in `users` table.
Don't use `$table->id('user_id');`, instead use `$table->id();` and this will generate column named `id`.

Or, if you want to name primary key column in `users` table as `user_id`, then you must change how you set foreign key:

```
Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
    ...
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
    ...
});
```

Comment: this happend when i try to change foreign key 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'user_id' in foreign key constraint 'posts_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`user_id`)) should i change the type ?